# Different ways to create Javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I want to understand the performance difference for constructing arrays. Running the following program, I am puzzled by the output below:

```
Time for range0: 521
Time for range1: 149
Time for range2: 1848
Time for range3: 8411
Time for range4: 3487
```

I don't understand why 3 takes longer than 4, while 1 takes shorter than 2. Also, seems the map function is very inefficient; what is the use of it?

---

```js
function range0(start, count) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        arr.push(start + i);
    }
    return arr;
}

function range1(start, count) {
    var arr = new Array(count);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        arr[i] = start + i;
    }
    return arr;
}

function range2(start, count) {
    var arr = Array.apply(0, Array(count));
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        arr[i] = start + i;
    }
    return arr;
}

function range3(start, count) {
    var arr = new Array(count);
    return arr.map(function(element, index) {
        return index + start;
    });
}

function range4(start, count) {
    var arr = Array.apply(0, Array(count));
    return arr.map(function(element, index) {
        return index + start;
    });
}

function profile(range) {
    var iterations = 100000,
        start = 0, count = 1000,
        startTime, endTime, finalTime;

    startTime = performance.now();

    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        range(start, count);
    }

    endTime = performance.now();

    finalTime = (endTime - startTime);
    console.log(range.name + ': ' + finalTime + ' ms');
}

[range0, range1, range2, range3, range4].forEach(profile);
```

Comment: Modern engines have optimizations for pre-allocated, homogeneous arrays, so that likely explains `range1`.

Comment: `.map()` exists to take an existing array and create a new one of the same length using potentially complex logic to determine the value of each member based on current members. It's a very convenient method.

Comment: Because .map() has it's own job because `var arr = Array.apply(0, Array(count))` is a very ugly JS instruction..

Comment: Your `range3` doesn't actually work properly.

Comment: Using `apply` with very many arguments is most likely the main culprit here. Also notice that the use of `map` does create a second array, so it's quite incomparable to `range0` or `range1` when you want to measure the time to create *one* array.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why 3 takes longer than 4

Me neither. It is a surprising result, given my superficial analysis and the results I obtained by profiling the code. On my computer running Google Chrome 50, `range4` is twice as slow compared to `range3`.

I'd have to study the Javascript implementation you are using in order to figure out why that happens.

> while 1 takes shorter than 2.

`range1` executes faster because it uses a loop and optimizes memory allocations, while `range2` uses functions and does unnecessary memory allocations.

> Also, seems the map function is very inefficient; what is the use of it?

The [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is used to compute a new `Array` based on the values of an existing one.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(number => number * number);
// [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

---

## On my computer

```
Time for range0: 783
Time for range1: 287
Time for range2: 10541
Time for range3: 14981
Time for range4: 28243
```

My results reflect my expectations regarding the performance of each function.

## A superficial analysis of each function

- `range0`

  Creates an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and populates it via a loop. It is the most simple and straightforward code possible. I suppose it could be understood as the *baseline* for performance comparison.
- `range1`

  Uses the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax) with a length parameter. This greatly optimizes the underlying memory allocation required to store the elements. Since the exact number of elements is known beforehand, the memory does not have to be [`realloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)ated as the number of elements grows; the exact amount of memory needed to store all elements can be allocated exactly once, when the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is instantiated.
- `range2`

  [Applies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) an *empty* arguments list to the constructor function, with `this` set to the number `0`. This is semantically equivalent to [`Array()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax) – the fact the arguments list was created with a `count` parameter has no bearing on the result of the function application. In fact, it needlessly wastes time allocating memory for an *empty* arguments list.

  You probably meant to use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

  ```
    Array.call(null, count)
  ```
- `range3`

  Like `range1`, but uses [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a function instead of a loop. The initial memory allocation is optimized, but the overhead of calling the function `count` times is likely to be huge.

  In addition, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) generates a new [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instance. Since that instance also has `count` elements, it would make sense to optimize *that* memory allocation as well, however it is unclear to me whether that actually happens. Nevertheless, two separate memory allocations are taking place, instead of just one as in `range1`.
- `range4`

  Combines all the inefficiencies of `range2` and `range3`.

  Amazingly, it executes faster than `range3` on your computer. It's unclear to me why that happened. I suppose one would have to investigate your Javascript particular implementation in order to figure it out.

Comment: I run the code on nodeJS 4.4.5.  The nodeJs engine must have done some good thing to optimize range4. I agree Array.apply(null, Array(count)) is not a proper way to create an empty array. I copied the code from some samples. Definitely should use Array.call(null, count) instead.